# Set run-direction of text in Acrofields using iText 5.5

Tags: itext, arabic, acrofields

I have to set the text-direction of some Arabic data as RTL. Is this achievable through acrofields? Please guide.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arabic Data disappears on Form flattening in iText](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305574/arabic-data-disappears-on-form-flattening-in-itext)

Comment: Hi Bruno, I can see the Arabic text on my screen now but its run direction is not RTL. Is there any alternative to columntext.setrundirection() in acrofields?

Comment: I don't understand Arabic, so I can't help you. Please ask somebody who has experience with Arabic.

Comment: Okay! I was jus wondering if it is possible to inject a columntext to an acrofield..Can this be done?