# Cannot show special character in acro form field

Tags: itext

I tried to use the following code to set form field value with iText but it could not show the character **ӧ**. The test-form-fill.pdf is created by Adobe LifeCycle Form Designer. Please help!

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("doc/test-form-fill.pdf");
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("doc/test-form-fill-done.pdf");

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(is);

PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, os);


AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();

form.setField("field1", "ӧ11111");

stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
stamper.close();
reader.close();


is.close();

os.close();
```

Comment: This question has been answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24305574/arabic-data-disappears-on-form-flattening-in-itext I would like to mark this question as duplicate, but one can only select accepted answers or an answer with an at least one up-vote.

Answer (score 0):

The `ӧ` character probably doesn't show up because the font that is used for the form field doesn't know how to draw that character. Take a look at the [FillFormSpecialChars2](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/acroforms/FillFormSpecialChars2) example resulting in [form_special_chars.pdf](http://itextpdf.com/sites/default/files/form_special_chars.pdf):

[image]

You need to define a substitution font like this:

```
public void manipulatePdf(String src, String dest) throws DocumentException, IOException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader,
            new FileOutputStream(dest));
    AcroFields fields = stamper.getAcroFields();
    BaseFont bf = BaseFont.createFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED, false, null, null, false);
    fields.setFieldProperty("Name", "textfont", bf, null);
    fields.setField("Name", "\u04e711111");
    stamper.setFormFlattening(true);
    stamper.close();
}
```

In my case, `FONT` refers to FreeSans:

```
public static final String FONT = "resources/fonts/FreeSans.ttf";
```

FreeSans knows how to draw an `ӧ`, but feel free to replace `FONT` with a path to any other font that supports these characters.

As you can see, I also changed `ӧ` into `\u04e7` which protects your code against encoding problems.